# React Router v5 - Clicking <Link /> is not re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router

As I understand, clicking on React Router's `<Link />` component should cause everything inside `<Router />` to re-render.

However, it seems like that is not the case in this simple example app using React Router DOM v5.2:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Foo = () => {
  console.log("rendered");
  return null;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Foo />
      <div className="App">
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <br />
        <Link to="/foo">Foo</Link>

        <Route path="/" exact>
          <p>Home</p>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/foo">
          <p>Foo</p>
        </Route>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-water-2fuxt?file=/src/App.js

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you not have an `Route` components registered with paths?

Comment: I'll add that to see if it makes a difference

Comment: `Route` are critical components for routing. They correlate to the `to` property of `Link` to render content at a specified path.

Comment: Hmm, I see that now. I guess I was expecting all children of  `<Router>` to re-render but it seems that only children of `<Route>` re-render. And, it seems that not all `<Route>`s re-render

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "expecting all children of Router to re-render"? Do you mean that when you go to path `/foo` that correlates to a specific component/jsx inside a specific `Route` that other routes/pages render also? If you are on `/foo` you want `/` to separately re-render?

Comment: I've updated the codesandbox to make this simpler to discuss. Take a look at the route containing `<Foo />`. Currently, there is not `path` prop so it always renders. Because of this, `<Foo />` never unmounts when pathname changes (and it never re-renders when pathname changes). However, when we instead specify `path` for the route containing `<Foo />`, e.g. `<Route path="/" exact>`, now `<Foo />` renders each time that component gets mounted. Makes sense, but I didn't fully understand that before

Comment: Previously, I thought that _any_ child of `<Router>` would re-render whenever pathname changed. That's just not true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *actually* render `Foo` on a route with path then it rerenders when that path is matched. A route without a path will ***always*** match and be rendered, so it is rendered when it mounts and doesn't rerender since it has no props nor any state to update (*it would if the component containing the `Router` remounts/updates*).

Renders once per render of `Router`

```
<Route>
  <Foo />
</Route>
```

Rerenders once per path match

```
<Route path="/foo">
  <Foo />
</Route>
```

Consider this demo

```
const Foo = () => {
  console.log("rendered Foo");
  return null;
};
const Bar = () => {
  console.log("rendered Bar");
  return null;
};

export default function App() {
  const [c, setC] = useState(0);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Route>
        <Foo />
      </Route>

      <button onClick={() => setC(c => c + 1)}>Rerender Router</button>

      <div className="App">
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <br />
        <Link to="/bar">Bar</Link>

        <Route path="/" exact>
          <p>Home</p>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/bar">
          <Bar />
        </Route>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit peaceful-chebyshev-2k8rc]

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand, clicking on React Router's `<Link />` component should cause everything inside `<Router />` to re-render.

not `<Router />` but `<Route />` only if the specified path matches the current path.

the children of `<Router />` will only be rendered once.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `<link/>` by `<a/>` tag, an example

```
<a href="/bar">Bar</a>
```